# Get Specific Info From SQL Error Message 547

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

How do I correctly extract specific info from an sql error message number 547?

Info Required:

- Table Name
- Constraint Name
- Column Name

Code:

```
Try 
  ....
Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException 
        If ex.Number = 547 Then

        End If
End Try
```

Sample message:

> UPDATE statement conflicted with COLUMN CHECK constraint
>   'CK_Birthdate'. The conflict occurred in database 'Northwind', table
>   'Employees', column 'BirthDate'.

Comment: Do you only care about (say) US English versions of this message? And one specific SQL Server version...

Comment: I need it to be stable for multiple versions of sql but only US english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no straight forward way of getting these pieces of information separately.

It all gets concatenated into the error message.

You can use `select * from sys.messages where message_id=547` to see the various different language formats of the message that you would need to deal with in order to extract the constituent parts then perhaps use regular expressions with capturing groups based around this information.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but probably as good as it gets.  Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to queries, here's a powershell script which wraps the sys.messages queries.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2009/04/30/and-the-winner-is-get-sql-server-error-messages-from-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 0):

*its true there is no straight way to fix this but I did this insted*

```
var str = sqlException.Message.ToString();
var strlist = str.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var streplace = strlist[1];
streplace = streplace.Replace("table \"dbo.", "");
streplace = streplace.Replace("\"", ""); //this will get the data table name 
streplace = string.Concat(streplace.Select(x => Char.IsUpper(x) ? " " + x : x.ToString())).TrimStart(' ');
```